# Firefox is not obeying HTML5 "HIDDEN" attribute when using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

The button "Delete My Account" is supposed to remove the HIDDEN class from the second button, therefore showing the second button after a click. It does this perfectly, but Firefox also shows the button even with the HIDDEN  attribute set. After the click it does update the second button and remove the attribute, but the display stays the same because Firefox still wants to display the button either way. I need the second button to display only after the first button is clicked, but Firefox is freaking out, why could this be?

**Pre-Click**
[image: Pre-Click]
**Post-Click**
[image: Post-Click]

Comment: Maybe instead of `hidden` try adding/subtracting a class with `display: none`? [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) mentions that setting any display properties overwrites `hidden`.

Comment: Can you show the all computed styles for the `<a>` when `hidden` is present? Just wondering.

Comment: I got it, using display: none worked, because of Bootstrap overwriting the hidden attribute because I'm using flexboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Bootstrap, the display value is already set in Bootstrap's CSS, so setting hidden as an attribute just got overwritten in Firefox because display takes precedence over the hidden attribute. So, using `document.getElementById('buttonConfirmDelete').removeAttribute('style');` on the onclick of the first button, you would then delete the style containing `display: none` of the other button, then showing it.

Comment: Boo, I shoulda answered and gotten them sweet points. :p Glad to hear it's resolved!

Comment: Haha yea sorry, right when I saw `display: none` in your comment I knew, 'Oh crap, Bootstrap sets the display value when it loads, duh!'